# How do I change the theme in my Scout project to the default theme?

Tags: eclipse-scout

I'm following the `Eclipse Scout Beginner's Guide` and in the [section about switching to the default theme](https://eclipsescout.github.io/8.0/beginners-guide.html#sec-contacts_default_theme). It says to comment out the following line in the `config.properties` file in order to use the default theme:

```
scout.ui.theme=application
```

I do that and restart the application but I see no change in the theme. Is this a known issue? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Scout application remembers the last used theme in a browser cookie in the value `scout.ui.theme`.

This means that if you change the default to different theme, you'll need to clear this cookie or the private browsing mode of your browser to see the effect.